# How to deal with update the partitional binding data request instead of the all column in playframework

Tags: forms, scala, playframework-2.0, submit

I use playframework2 and slick2 just mapping of part of my data to the form, when the form update, how to only partly updating?

the Form is:

```
val partForm = Form(
mapping(
"first_name" -> text(),
 "second_name" -> text(),
 "id"-> text(),
 "Address"->ignored(""), //this field is ignore
 "status"->ignored(""),  //this field is ignore
 ...
 )(User.apply)(User.unapply)
)
```

when submit the form:

```
  def submit = DBAction { implicit rs =>

partForm.bindFromRequest.fold(
  formWithErrors => BadRequest(html.group.admin(formWithErrors)),
  user => {
    if (user.id.isDefined) {
      UserTable.update(user)
    } else {
      UserTable.insert(user)
    }

    Home.flashing("success" -> "User %s has been saved".format(user.name))
  }
)
}
```

But this update will update all form information including I ignored columns, I want simpling update the corresponding edited columns, how to do it?

Answer (score 0):

IIRC, Slick does not yet support partial updates so the best you can do is to either query the DB for an existing user's record:

```
if (user.id.isDefined) {
  val u = UserTable.get(user.id) // get existing user instance
  UserTable.update(u.copy(firstName = user.firstName, user.lastName = ...))
}
```

for each field you want to modify, or, rather than ignoring fields, use `default` instead and store these fields in hidden fields in your form (the latter will save you an extra trip to the DB).

If you take the query route then using a MutatingUnitInvoker (name may have changed in latest Slick) is best as you can modify an existing DB row in place vs. getting and updating in 2 separate queries.

p.s. if you prefer, this

```
if (user.id.isDefined) {
  UserTable.update(user)
} else {
  UserTable.insert(user)
}
```

could be rewritten as

```
user.id map(UserTable.update(user)) getOrElse UserTable.insert(user)
```